# pooled OLS regression in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm using Stata/MP 13.0 for Mac.

I need to run a pooled OLS regression using Stata on a data set and have the cluster robust variance matrix. I know the `regress` command for a normal regression but how do I run a POLS regression ?

If someone knows as well a good text explaining POLS (Google wasn't my friend in that case).

When I `regress` lnwg on lnhr, I get the following results (Sorry I tried to screenshot it but the file format wasn't permitted:
A coefficient of .0827 for lnwg.

It is asked the effect of wages on labour supply. Can I simply say :One additional unit of wage leads to a increase of 8% of worked hours ?

Comment: Your edit (last two paragraphs) is just about the interpretation of a regression and doesn't raise a programming question. See any economics or statistics forum if a basic text does not make it clear to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My understanding of pooled OLS is that it is most appropriate when you have observational units observed in more than one time period, but individual units are not repeatedly observed across periods. Under this sampling scheme, the observations form different time periods are pooled together and OLS is conducted on the pooled sample.

This differentiates it from a panel (or longitudinal) sample where the same observational units are repeatedly observed. In this case, the researcher typically uses a within (fixed effects) or similar estimator to sweep out unobserved heterogeneity in the individuals.

If the researcher has strong reasons to believe that such heterogeneity does not exist, she may choose to use the pooled OLS on a longitudinal sample. This is typically not advisable. The reverse is not true: If the sample is pooled, the researcher cannot use the standard fixed effects methods.

This being said, the `regress` command is the correct tool for the job. It is typical to also include a time fixed effect to control for changes that affect the sample over time. As such, your command would look something like this:

```
reg Y X1 X2 i.timeVar, robust
```

You can capture the variance-covariance matrix using the following immediately after `reg`;

```
matrix myVarCovar =e(V)
```

and see it using

```
 matrix list myVarCovar
```

See `help matrix` for additional methods of working with this matrix.

Also, there are numerous posts on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) that may be more helpful in understanding pooled OLS.

Comment: Very helpful comment. Does it mean that if i want to get the default variance matrix AND the cluster robust variance matrix i need to regress once without the command "robust" and capture the matrix and regress another time but now with "robust" to get the cluster robust variance matrix ? What is the difference between cluster option and vce(robust) option ?

Comment: It is my understanding that you have to run the regressions twice. The `robust` or `vce(robust)` option is a asymptotically robust to heteroskedasticity. The `cluster(varname)` or `vce(cluster varname)` option is robust to heteroskedasticity and allows for arbitrary correlation within varname. You can read more about this in the help files: `help reg` and `help vce_option`.